# How to autostart a service with systemd from a user's home?

Tags: systemd, autostart

I configured a unit which is expected to run simple logging service:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/msgwriter.service 
[Unit]
Description=Writes the values of the counter to the file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/user/dev/start
```

The problem is home directory is encrypted. There is an error in the system's logs:

> **systemd[1018]:** msgwriter.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/user/dev/start: No such file or directory

I know I can move my service into `/usr/local/bin`. But the final goal is to start it as a user.

Comment: Why not move the service to `/usr/local/bin` and use `User=dev` in the `[Service]` section? So long as the user can read `/usr/local/bin` it wouldn't be an issue, and would make it easy to run the service as another user if you wanted.

Comment: I consider this as a workaround. But I prefer to keep the service's config files on encrypted volume for 2 reasons: 1) they contain a sensitive information, which must not leak if PC is stolen; 2) it is convenient for me to edit configs and/or update a service files in the home dir when I login by ssh.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `RequiresMountsFor=/home` to the `[Unit]` section of the .service file